# Element moves after transforming

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a span within the .btn rotate 180 deg when I click the .btn. However, the span also moved to the right and went down after it was rotated. Could anyone help me explain why it moved like that.
I tried to transform: translate(-21px, 1px) after rotation then the span will moved the right place but I believe there will be another better way to fix it. I also tried transform-origin: 50% 50% but it doesn't work either.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
})
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway";
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-family: "Raleway", "Microsoft JhengHei", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #7a7b7c;
}

.btn {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #6F7272;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2rem #babbbc;
  position: absolute;
}
.btn span {
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}
.btn::before, .btn::after {
  content: "";
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}
.btn::before {
  margin-top: -7px;
}
.btn::after {
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.open {
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #6F7272;
}
.open span {
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try setting `transform-origin` property?

Comment: @Abinthatha yes, I did but it dosen't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach isn't working as expected, because after click event, you are transforming the `X` & `Y` values of your `span` using `translate` property and then `rotating` it. This causes it to shift it's location when transformed.

You used `position: absolute` to place your `span` in middle. this can be also be achieved via other CSS properties like `display: table` or `display :flex`

Check out the below suggestion - most of the code is all yours with just slight change.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
})
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway";
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-family: "Raleway", "Microsoft JhengHei", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #7a7b7c;
}

.btn {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #6F7272;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2rem #babbbc;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn span {
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /*  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute; */
}

.btn::before,
.btn::after {
  content: "";
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}

.btn::before {
  margin-top: -7px;
}

.btn::after {
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.open {
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #6F7272;
}

.open span {
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I understood why it happens. I better use flex in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove   `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` and just keep `left:26%` and `top: 49%` It works fine.

To your question why it is happening. Because you have moved it using left and top position and again you are trying to neutralise it by translate. which is moving the center of animation to different position.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
})
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway";
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-family: "Raleway", "Microsoft JhengHei", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #7a7b7c;
}

.btn {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #6F7272;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2rem #babbbc;
  position: absolute;
}
.btn span {
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  top: 49%;
  left: 26%;
//  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}
.btn::before, .btn::after {
  content: "";
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}
.btn::before {
  margin-top: -7px;
}
.btn::after {
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.open {
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #6F7272;
}
.open span {
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think using transform: translate() will cause change the center point of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Update this style

```
.open span {
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transform: rotate(180deg) translate(20px, 1px );
}
```

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
})
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway";
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-family: "Raleway", "Microsoft JhengHei", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #7a7b7c;
}

.btn {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #6F7272;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2rem #babbbc;
  position: absolute;
}
.btn span {
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}
.btn::before, .btn::after {
  content: "";
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}
.btn::before {
  margin-top: -7px;
}
.btn::after {
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.open {
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #6F7272;
}
.open span {
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(20px, 1px );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was one of my solution. I tried
transform: rotate(180deg) translate(20px, 1px); and I works well but I don't know why did the span move after rotating.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is what you are trying to achieve.

Here, I have added a single line to the css `transform-origin: 10px;`. Everything else is the same. The change in JS is to remove the `add` class as soon as the animation carried out. Otherwise, you will need to click double times on the button to see the animation again.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  $(this).addClass('open');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.btn').removeClass('open');
  }, 300);
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-family: "Raleway", "Microsoft JhengHei", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #7a7b7c;
}

.btn {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #6F7272;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2rem #babbbc;
  position: absolute;
}
.btn span {
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}
.btn::before, .btn::after {
  content: "";
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}
.btn::before {
  margin-top: -7px;
}
.btn::after {
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.open {
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #6F7272;
}
.open span {
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: The result is what I expected. However I couldn't understand why the span moved like. I supposed transform-origin is at mid point of the span. Am I correct ?

Comment: Not exactly, we can set the transform-origin at the point where we want, it can be left, right, center or user-specific. Please check https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/transform-origin/.

Comment: Thank you, I just briefly read the material and it says "The default value of the transform origin is at 50% 50%, which is exactly the center of any given element." as I expected. And in my case, I expected the span would stay in the same place after rotating which means transform-origin: 50% 50%. However, the span moved to somewhere that made me confuse. As @Tusha and Deepak said, it happened because I tried to put the span in the middle using translate.